# add componentsseparatedbystring into a predicate with core data

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

i have a String stored in an Entity (core data) i want to use an NSFetchedResultsController to get data.

string format: abc,ba,x,s,d.  this is an array of IDs saved as string.

i want to get only entities that contains at least an IDs in that string.

the problem is if i use CONTAIN in the predicate and search for "a" i will get a wrong result.

could you please tel me if it's possible to add something like "componentsseparatedbystring" in a predicate so i can iterate and use "in"in the result or if there's an other solution, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "MATCHES" operator in a predicate, which does a
regular expression match:

```
NSString *searchID = @"a";
NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(^|.*,)%@(,.*|$)",
                     [NSRegularExpression escapedPatternForString:searchID]];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ID MATCHES %@", pattern];
```

The pattern `(^|.*,)TERM(,.*|$)` searches for `TERM` which is preceded
by either the start of the string or a comma, and followed by the
end of the string or another comma.

Answer (score 0):

First convert your array of ID's into an NSArray:

```
NSArray *arrayOfIds = [stringOfIds componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Then use an IN predicate on your fetch:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ID IN %@", arrayOfIds];
```

this assumes your database column is called "ID", and your comma-separated string of ID's is stringOfIds.

Comment: as i say, i have absolute to use the array returned by an nsfetched result so i can't use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

finally i will use a dirty solution: we have 4 possibilities:

1. string format= a
2. string format= a,..
3. string format= ..,a
4. string format= ..,a,..

so the predicate could be:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ID LIKE %@ OR
ID CONTAINS %@ OR
ID CONTAINS %@ OR 
ID ENDSWITH %@)",
searchedID,
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,", searchedID],
[NSString stringWithFormat:@",%@", searchedID],
[NSString stringWithFormat:@",%@,", searchedID]]
```

but this is a dirty solution, i really want something cleaner.